# Main site on domain but blog on subdomain with same WP install

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, subdomain

I have a running site on http://www.MyDomain.com and all is OK, but instead of making http://www.MyDomain.com/blog my default Blog page I want to use same this same WP install and make default blog page to be on subdomain: blog.MyDomain.com
Is this possible with single WP install and without using iframes and how ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am testing something and I was wondering if this is doable. I am using WP on main domain as a CMS and I want to move blogs to subdomain blog.MySite.com....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

and remove any of the old WP_SITEURL definitions that you may have in there.

Comment: That's just going to let you access the same site at different addresses, isn't it?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Thought that was what OP wanted

Comment: I think he wants to serve different content at blog.domain.com, but using the same wordpress install. So blog posts would appear at blog.domain.com but the rest of the site would be on domain.com.  Seems like it's better to just create a new WP install.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert - that is exactly what I want to have same WP install but to point Blog to subdomain. Is that possible at all ?

Comment: Maybe with WP multisite, but I think two installs makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Well, I was hoping this was doable by using single install WP and without enabling multisite anyway - thanks for the help.